# how to set the innerHTML of HTML drop down list in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, internet-explorer

I have one html drop down list and button.

```
 <select style="width:170px" id="ddl"></select>
  <input type="button" value="getvalue" onclick="abc()" />
```

when i click this button , i need to change the innerHTML of drop down list.for that, i am calling one javascript fuction. it is working all other browser except IE. i am using IE8 version.so i don't know whether it will works on other IE versions

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function abc()
    {
        var a = "<option selected='selected'   value='TN_Pulling'>TN_Pulling</option>";
        document.getElementById('ddl').innerHTML = a;
    }
</script>
```

please help me to sort it out. did i missed anything ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code worked on my IE11, but not on my IE8.

This worked on my IE8:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function abc()
{
    document.getElementById('ddl').innerHTML = ''; // clear <select> contents
    var a = document.createElement('option');      // create an <option> elem
    a.setAttribute('value', 'TN_Pulling');         // set 'value' attr val
    a.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');        // set 'selected' attr val
    a.innerHTML = 'TN_Pulling';                    // set <option> contents
    document.getElementById('ddl').appendChild(a); // append <option> to <select>
}
</script>
<select style="width:170px" id="ddl"></select>
<input type="button" value="getvalue" onclick="abc()" />
```

Good Luck.