# Javascript Functions in IE7

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I'm editing part of a web page that allows users to pick their pain rating on three different scales of pain. My code works fine on Chrome and newer versions of IE and Firefox, but in IE 8 and under it fails. This code has to work on browsers as old as IE 7.

```js
var painByScale = {
  FLACC: ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
  Wong_Baker: ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
  UAB: ["", "0", "0.5", "1", "1.5", "2", "2.5", "3", "3.5", "4", "4.5", "5", "5.5", "6", "6.5", "7", "7.5", "8", "8.5", "9", "9.5", "10"]
}

function changerate(value) {
  if (value == "");
  else if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("pain_scale").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var options = "";
    for (painId in painByScale[value]) {
      options += "<option>" + painByScale[value][painId] + "</option>";
    }
    document.getElementById("pain").innerHTML = options;
  }
}
```

```html
<select name="pain_scale" tabindex="40" id="pain_scale" onChange="changerate(this.value);">
  <option value="" selected>Select Scale</option>
  <option value="FLACC">FLACC</option>
  <option value="Wong_Baker">Wong-Baker</option>
  <option value="UAB">UAB</option>
</select>
<select name="pain" id="pain">
  <option value="" selected>Select Rating</option>
</select>
```

I'm not the best at building websites but I've tried everything I know how to do. If anyone has any advice, please help me out. Any Advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Old IEs fail when you're setting `innerHTML` of `select` element. Create an option element, and append it to select element instead. Also don't use `for .. in` to iterate an array, a regular `for` loop should be used instead. Also, it's questionable, if those IEs are worth of supporting.

Comment: What does it mean: *but in IE 8 and under **it fails***? Do you get any errors?

Comment: The error I get is in the HTML after the first line: "The value of the property 'changerate' is null or undefined, not a Function object"

Comment: @Teemu I'll try working on that, thanks. I''l keep the post updated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32799539/how-to-set-the-innerhtml-of-html-drop-down-list-in-ie

Comment: That error you're getting is actually not a problem with the method definition, but, as @Teemu pointed out, because of the `for .. in` loop. Other 'advanced' for loops, like `for .. of` and `forEach`, don't work in IE 8 and below.

Comment: There's also a trailing comma in `painByScale`, it's a syntax error in old IEs. That's most likely the reason for the error, the function is never defined, since the script execution brakes before it.

Comment: so how would I go about changing that loop? don't entirely know how I can sift through those arrays without the for in loop @MaclainAnderson

Comment: `for ... in` is perfectly valid every where and in old IEs as well.

Comment: @jayarjo You are correct, it seems. My mistake

Comment: `onChange="changerate(this.value);"` also looks faulty to me, that's not how you access the value of the `select`, try `this.options[this.selectedIndex].value`

Comment: @jayarjo I've always used the value of the select in my JS. Never had an issue there. It just has the value of whichever option is selected.

Comment: Have you tried to use it in IE8 and below?

Comment: @Xander Well, as pointed out, `for .. in` does work in IE8 and below, so that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Problem still persists when I add onChange="changerate(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);

Comment: @jayarjo I'm testing this on IE7 and on IE8

Comment: I added a console.log in the function to keep track of the value each time it's changed, and the value is definitely being passed into the function properly. The code is just not populating anything into the second dropdown list.

Comment: That's the whole different error then. Check my updated answer.

Comment: The `gEBI` works fine in your code (names and ids are not conflicting). It's not clear what you want your code actually do, but as I've stated in my first comment, in IE7 there's no `innerHTML` for `select` elements (it was a native OS element at that time in IE). See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bvxtLa54/), it is supposed to be IE7 compliant code, which creates some options to `#pain` element when you change the selection in `#pain_scale`. JsFiddle doesn't support any version of IE, so you've to copy the code to your own files to test it in any IE.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Replacing `innerHTML` in `select` is not working in old IEs as well (if I remember correctly). Replace the whole `select` element at once maybe.

```js
var painByScale = {
  FLACC: ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
  Wong_Baker: ["", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
  UAB: ["", "0", "0.5", "1", "1.5", "2", "2.5", "3", "3.5", "4", "4.5", "5", "5.5", "6", "6.5", "7", "7.5", "8", "8.5", "9", "9.5", "10"]
}

function changerate(value) {
  if (value == "");
  else if (value.length == 0) document.getElementById("pain_scale").innerHTML = "<option></option>";
  else {
    var options = '<select name="pain" >';
    for (var painId in painByScale[value]) {
      options += "<option value=" + painByScale[value][painId] + ">" + painByScale[value][painId] + "</option>";
    }

    options += "</select>";
    document.getElementById("pain").innerHTML = options;
  }
}
```

```css
#pain {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<select name="pain_scale" tabindex="40" id="pain_scale" onChange="changerate(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);">
  <option value="" selected>Select Scale</option>
  <option value="FLACC">FLACC</option>
  <option value="Wong_Baker">Wong-Baker</option>
  <option value="UAB">UAB</option>
</select>
<div id="pain">
  <select name="pain">
    <option value="" selected>Select Rating</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: that wasn't quite it, that's actually a remnant from something I was trying right before I made this post

Comment: i didn't downvote you, check my reputation, my votes aren't public. don't know who did

Comment: some lame-o dork probably

Comment: where is that display: inline-block supposed to go? and yeah, thats a good idea. doesn't work right away but if I tweak this I can probably get a working site

Comment: It's just a style to inline that wrapping `div`, you can put it wherever your styles are.

Comment: got it. appreciate the help. going to come back to this one tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably running sites in compatibility view.  I can't imagine a company still using IE7 on purpose ;) What I've done is use this meta tag in my header.  It forces the browser to use the most recent version of IE.  Otherwise, you're going to have to refactor your code.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
```

Comment: this was my initial idea but it's a no-go because several forms on this page require old browser support. hospitals and doctors offices, i find, are the only ones still relying on ancient IE versions!

Comment: Ok, try this out.  I saw something about IE7 having issues with document.getElementById.  https://www.impressivewebs.com/avoiding-problems-with-javascript-getelementbyid-method-in-internet-explorer-7/